# Point between two polygons how to find to which it belongs?

Tags: algorithm, polygon, shapes, area

[image]

What algorithm to use so that we can determine that if the red dot belongs to Area1 or Area2.
my original idea was to divide the polygons into triangles using consecutive points and then use a known algorithm to determine if a point belongs to one of these triangles however there is a problem shown in the figure.p4 p5 p6 are point in Area 1 but they make a triangle in area 2.

Answer (score 4):

Continue inifite ray from red point to any direction. Count intesections of such ray with any polygon. Even count of intersections indicates that point lies outside of polygon

Answer (score 2):

You can use the idea of the polygon filling algorithm for that. If you know the vertices of a polygon, you can lay a horizontal ray through the red point and count the vertices it intersects. If the count is even, it is outside, otherwise it is inside.

If you imagine coming from the far left along that ray, the first intersection is entering the polygon, the second is leaving it, the third is entering again... and so on. So if the number is odd (1,3,5,...) you are inside the polygon when you hit the point, otherwise you are outside.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the idea -

1. Draw a horizontal line to the right of red point and extend it to infinity
2. Count the number of times the line intersects with polygon edges.
3. A point is inside the polygon if either count of intersections is odd or
   point lies on an edge

See [Check if a point lies inside or outside a polygon](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-if-a-given-point-lies-inside-a-polygon/).